# Disable some/all radio buttons in Android preference

Tags: java, android

I have searched and searched Google, Stack Overflow, etc. for an answer to this and failed!

I wish to programatically disable/enable selected radio buttons in a single Android preference.

For example, there is a radio button preference with 6 choices, but depending on some condtions (not related to the preferences) some of them will be unselectable and should be shown as disabled.

I can see how we can disable complete radio button groups, but not individual radio buttons

Can Anyone help?

Comment: consider extending that class and do it by yourself..

Comment: check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827980/selecting-and-deselecting-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not supported by the built-in `ListPreference`. You are welcome to write your own custom `Preference`, or perhaps extend `ListPreference`, where you supply your own `Adapter` and disable certain items that way.

Comment: OK - I now know that there is not much point in looking for supported mechanisms to do this - I will look to examples of extending the  ListPreference  class...